# How to erase non-alphabet characters from a string without going out of range

Tags: c++

I am trying to this function to return without numbers, spaces, or other characters and I am supposed to use the .erase function. I understand that my loop keeps going out of range, but I have no clue how to fix it and I've been stuck on this for a while. If the user types "dogs are a lot of fun" and I need the function to return and output "dogsarealotoffun" Thanks for the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

//function to output string without spaces, numbers, or punctuations        
string alphabetOnly (string input){
    int size;
    int i= 0;
    size = (int)input.size();

    while (input[i] < size){
        if (isalpha(input[i])){
            i++;
        }         
        else
            input.erase(input[i]);
    }
    return input;
}

int main() {
    string input;

    cout << "Enter a string to test: ";
    getline(cin, input);

    cout << "alphabetOnly: " << alphabetOnly(input) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Try iterating backwards from the end of the string instead.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner will still lead up to potentially detrimental performance

Comment: Hint: look at `std::remove_if`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Comment: Your issue is that as you delete the characters the actual size is decreasing, but you are using a one-off calculation of size. Starting at the end avoids that issue, but you still end up moving each kept element many times. `std::remove_if` uses an internal trick to compact the list as it goes efficiently, only moving each item once, and runs from the start.

Comment: You have: while (input[i] < size){   You should really be doing while (i < size){ here

Comment: I am supposed you use the .erase() function and I haven't learned about remove if yet.

Comment: Well, the answer to the question stated in the title is to use `remove_if`.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't think performance is a concern in this context.  If it was, the questioner would not be restricted to only using `erase()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:** I was too hasty in my previous answer (as I am learning I need to speak from tested code rather than off the top of my head) and needed to debug. The problem is in the else case you need to erase the char, NOT increment i because the length of the string just changed, and also since the length of the string changed you need to reset size to be the new length. Sorry for the hasty answer earlier, I was speaking without actually using the compiled code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>


//function to output string without spaces, numbers, or punctuations
std::string alphabetOnly (std::string input){
    int size;
    int i= 0;
    size = (int)input.size();

    while (i < size){
        if (isalpha(input[i])){
            i++;
        }
        else{
            input.erase(i,1);
            //do not increment i here since the index changed becauase of erase
            size = (int)input.size();
        }
    }
    return input;
}

int main() {
    std::string input;

    std::cout << "Enter a string to test: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::cout << input;

    std::cout << "alphabetOnly: " << alphabetOnly(input) << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I'm getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: ok, sorry I had to debug, just fixed the issues. But as others say there are better methods to do this. But, if you want to do it your way, here is a way I have tested to work.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I'm was looking for.

Comment: No problem, if you downvoted earlier can you reverse it now that I fixed the answer?

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

//function to output string without spaces, numbers, or punctuations        
std::string alphabetOnly (std::string input)
{
    auto not_alpha = [](char c) { return !std::isalpha(c); };
    input.erase(std::remove_if(begin(input), 
                               end(input), 
                               not_alpha), 
                std::end(input));
    return input;
}

int main() {
    std::string input;

    std::cout << "Enter a string to test: ";
    getline(std::cin, input);

    std::cout << "alphabetOnly: " << alphabetOnly(input) << std::endl;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/340465d41ecd8c8e

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few things wrong with your code, but to start with here's your main error corrected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

//function to output string without spaces, numbers, or punctuations
string alphabetOnly (string input){
int size;
int i= 0;
size = (int)input.size();

while (i < size){
    if(isalpha(input[i]))
    {
        i++;
    }
    else
       input.erase(input.begin( ) + i );
}
return input;
}

int main() {
string input;

cout << "Enter a string to test: ";
getline(cin, input);

cout << "alphabetOnly: " << alphabetOnly(input) << endl;
}
```

But this is awfully inefficient because you swhift all the remaining unchecked characters each time you delete.

You should use something like

```
input.erase( remove_if( input.begin(), input.end(), not( isalpha ) ), input.end( ));
```

This is known as the remove-erase idiom, whihc you can lookup anywhere.